# How to replace words using wildcards in MS Word 2013?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, wildcard

I am having a word document which is containing many words like this. I have shown below.

```
(00:05), (01:18), (09:45), (21:42)
```

How do I remove these words with single expression using wildcards?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Search and Replace dialog, you have "More >>" and you will be able to see the "Use wildcards" option. After tick, you can search \(*:*\).

Before :

```
(00:05), (01:18), (09:45), (21:42)
```

After :

```
, , ,
```

Comment: Lianhua, Thanks for your time but there is no "," in words, I have just separated words. Can you please tell me now, what to do exactly?

Comment: Thank you Lianhua!! You made my day. Thanks so much!!